# Facebook Check-in Functionality in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

I am implementing Check-in functionality in my app.

I got the reference url

http://tylerwhitedesign.com/how-to-check-in-using-the-facebook-ios-sdk-and-graph-api

as per login method :

```
- (void) login {

permissions = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"user_checkins", @"friends_checkins", @"publish_checkins", nil] retain];

[ facebook authorize:appID permissions:permissions delegate:self];
}
```

**But in my facebook sdk : 
 there is no method for support "
 [ facebook authorize:appID permissions:permissions delegate:self];"**

Help me for download latest Facebook SDK or Give sample code for Check-in functionality in iphone??

Answer (score 0):

Signing a user in using the `FacebookSDK` takes more than a block of code. I'm not really familiar with the specific build that you're using. But going off of the [Facebook Developer Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/ios/), logging in a user would roughly look like this:

```
- (void)createAndPresentLoginView
{
    if (self.loginViewController == nil) {
        self.loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController"
                                                                           bundle:nil];
        self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.loginViewController];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
    }
}

- (void)showLoginView
{
    if (self.loginViewController == nil) {
        [self createAndPresentLoginView];
    } else {
        [self.loginViewController loginFailed];
    }
}

- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState)state
                      error:(NSError *)error
{
    // FBSample logic
    // Any time the session is closed, we want to display the login controller (the user
    // cannot use the application unless they are logged in to Facebook). When the session
    // is opened successfully, hide the login controller and show the main UI.
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen: {
            // For gaining current location
            // [self.mainViewController startLocationManager];
            if (self.loginViewController != nil) {
                [self initializeTabBarController];
                [self.navController pushViewController:self.tabBarController animated:NO];
                self.loginViewController = nil;
            }

            // FBSample logic
            // Pre-fetch and cache the friends for the friend picker as soon as possible to improve
            // responsiveness when the user tags their friends.
            FBCacheDescriptor *cacheDescriptor = [FBFriendPickerViewController cacheDescriptor];
            [cacheDescriptor prefetchAndCacheForSession:session];
        }
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed: {
            // FBSample logic
            // Once the user has logged out, we want them to be looking at the root view.
            UIViewController *topViewController = [self.navController topViewController];
            UIViewController *modalViewController = [topViewController presentedViewController];
            if (modalViewController != nil) {
                [topViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
            }
            [self.navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

            [self performSelector:@selector(showLoginView)
                       withObject:nil
                       afterDelay:0.5f];
        }
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed: {
            // if the token goes invalid we want to switch right back to
            // the login view, however we do it with a slight delay in order to
            // account for a race between this and the login view dissappearing
            // a moment before
            [self performSelector:@selector(showLoginView)
                       withObject:nil
                       afterDelay:0.5f];
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:SCSessionStateChangedNotification
                                                        object:session];

    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error: %@",
                                                                     [ShindyAppDelegate FBErrorCodeDescription:error.code]]
                                                            message:error.localizedDescription
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}

- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI
{
    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                              allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                             [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                                         }];
}
```

However, you still need to get the [FacebookSDK](https://github.com/downloads/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/FacebookSDK-3.1.1.pkg) from the Facebook Developer's website. Also, you need to get a key called `SCSessionStateChangedNotification` that's specific to your application.

Best of luck!!